# Mxgraph with extjs window

Tags: extjs, mxgraph

Here is my simple example http://jsbin.com/muviperiji/8/edit. But not working 'delete' key press, tooltip positions. How can I solve these problems?

Comment: what error you've got? please explain more

Comment: @Milad, if you select any cell and press 'delete' key nothing happens. And position of tooltip (hover vertex) is outside of window, not near of vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set mxBasePath, update tooltip zIndex and use document.body in the key handler: http://jsbin.com/zufarixafo/1/edit